# icCube - Synchronise and refresh The Data Source Tables [Fixed Period]

Tags: database, configuration, iccube

On each time I update or change the data base, I must go to icCube server and clicked on

> "Rafraichir les tables de la source de données "

I want to fix a period or have a solution to refresh the data source automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those features are part of the Enterprise version (Scheduler, XMLA commands for managing the server ... ).